# How to make maven "add directory entries" when packaging?

Tags: java, jar, getresource

I have a program that makes use of `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` to obtain an URL to a directory, it works fine when in eclipse , but after jared , it returns null.

According to this url : 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/385935/java/java/getResource-path-fails-Jar

> The problem resulted because the path
>   itself did not exist in the jar. **The
>   files with the path existed, but not
>   the path itself**. I was using the
>   "Runnable JAR File" export command in
>   Eclipse. When I tried the older export
>   "Jar File" to create the jar, I
>   noticed a check box for "**add directory
>   entries**" and that was the solution.
>   The Jar file needed the directory
>   entry by itself in the jar for
>   getResource() to return the URL for
>   the path.

But in maven , I cannot find such commands to "add directory entries" when packaging , can someone give me a hint ? Thanks a lot !

Env : eclipse 3.5 , m2eclipse , maven 2.2.1

Comment: can you add you project structure and path to the file you are trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard maven 2 configuration, the directory and files would be placed under src/main/resources.  If they are elsewhere, you have to define where your resources are.

```
<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory>path to my resources</directory>
      </resource>
   </resources>
```

Comment: Thank you , but it seems not working ... maybe it is server's classloader issues ... (Resin)

Answer (score 0):

you would need to include an assembly descriptor and create your dirs.

Comment: Hi , can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

Assembly descriptor will help you solve this issue. Read up on the assembly plugin using this link http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html. If you still can't get it to work then let me know.